# “AS LOW AS:” price is showing the price including VAT (TAX) but should be without

Tags: price, tax, vat

I have a product which has tiered prices but when i search for the item it show the lowest prices but includes VAT (tax) how could i get it so the VAT is not included.

This is the block of code which displays the price.

```
<?php if ($this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() && $_minimalPriceValue && $_minimalPriceValue < $_convertedFinalPrice): ?>

        <?php $_minimalPriceDisplayValue = $_minimalPrice; ?>
        <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, array(0, 1, 4))): ?>
            <?php $_minimalPriceDisplayValue = $_minimalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmount; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($this->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="minimal-price-link">
        <?php endif ?>
        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('As low as:') ?></span>
        <span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_minimalPriceDisplayValue, false) ?>
            </span>


        <?php if ($this->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()): ?>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endif;
```

I have tried just taking out the

```
$_weeeTaxAmount
```

from the code but that did nothing if anyone could help that would be brilliant

Thank you

Comment: You need show the taxes in the frontend?

Comment: no i need it to display the price without the TAX included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need show taxes in frontend you can try this:

Go to:

```
System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Price Display Settings
```

Set te attribute:

**Display Product Prices In Catalog** -> Excluding Tax

Reindex and clean cache.

If you need show taxes you can try this:

Search:

```
$_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, $_simplePricesTax);
```

And change it by:

```
$_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue);
```

I hope will help you!

Comment: i need to show tax on product pages and checkout it is just on the products that display a low as price on product list pages and search results

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood you.

Search: $_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, $_simplePricesTax);

And convert by : 
$_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue);

Comment: Thank you if worked, if you can put that into your answer instead of the first answer i will accept it. Thank you again!