# Old price excluding tax, not displayed

Tags: price, tax, magento2.4.3.p1

In Magento 2.4.3 configuration, I have set:

**Display Product Prices In Catalog: Including and Excluding Tax**

If the product has a special price, then the only special price is displayed including/excluding tax, while the old price is displayed only as including tax.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try I have a manual solution for the `excl Regular Price`. You have to override the file in your theme

```
app\design\frontend\<VENDOR_NAME>\<THEME_NAME>\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml
```

and add content in to the file after the `old-price` `<span>`:

```
<span class="old-price">
    <span class="price-label">excl Regular Price</span>
    <span class="price-wrapper price-excluding-tax">
        <span class="price">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($priceModel->getAmount()->getBaseAmount(),2),true,false)?>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change 'price_type' to baseOldPrice.

```
<span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'baseOldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please can you follow this path in Backend :-

Admin >> Stores >> Configuration >> Sales >> Tax >> Price Display setting.

Hope this helpful thanks.

Comment: I have already mentioned in description, that I have set this to "Including and Excluding Tax"

Comment: This solution has been working fine. If you config and it doesn't work, please check your site again. It may be installed incorrectly or missing
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33056/101754